# Capturing output of sudo commands run over ssh (without password prompt)?

Tags: ssh, sudo, password, prompt, subshell

If I run this command, the output is what I expect, listing the directory `/root` on my server.

```
~ bash -c "ssh -t myserver 'sudo ls /root'"

Enter passphrase for key '/home/james/.ssh/ed25519': 
[sudo] password for myserver: 
snap
Connection to 167.172.xxx.xxx closed.
```

However, when I try to use a subshell to get that output into a variable, the ssh session hangs after I enter my ssh passphrase

```
➜  ~ var=$(bash -c "ssh -t myserver 'sudo ls /root'")

Enter passphrase for key '/home/james/.ssh/ed25519':
```

It just stays like that, pressing enter again does not make new lines, nothing happens until I cancel with ctrl-C.

Why does this work differently in a subshell, and how can I get the output of my ssh command into a local variable?

Edit: As @KamilMaciorowski pointed out, stderr and stdout are being combined into one (I can in fact type my password, and the captured output includes the password prompt as well as the expected output)

```
var=$(bash -c "ssh -t stash 'sudo ls /root'")
Connection to 167.172.xxx.xxx closed.
➜  ~ echo $var
[sudo] password for stash: 
snap
```

The thread he links to seems to indicate that what I want is not possible, so I guess just manipulating the output string is my best option, it works fine.

```
var=$(bash -c "ssh -t stash 'sudo ls /root'" | tail -n +2)
```

Still, is there is a nicer way to capture the output of a remote command to a local variable?

Comment: [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1557724/432690) where it says "You cannot tell them apart locally". "Them" meaning the remote stdout and the remote stderr. You're capturing them both to a variable/file locally.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Somehow I had not noticed that the password prompt was also being captured into the output. So I guess that takes me back to my original question.

Comment: Do you have full `sudo` rights on the remote server (i.e. can you `sudo -s`)? Follow-up question: do you have permission to make root-level changes on the remote server?

Comment: @roaima yes, I do and I can. I have to enter my password of course, as with everything else discussed. But I think the issue is what Kamil pointed out.. there is no way to separate stderr and stdout streams.